# How to re-export functions from a third-party module

Tags: zig

I have a module `foo.zig` which is useful but I want to augment it with more functions, without *modifying* it, so I created `foo-wrapper.zig` that has one or two more functions, and `foo.zig` has dozens of functions.

How do I re-export (with `pub` or something) all functions from `foo.zig` to all consumers of `foo-wrapper.zig`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just declare the function name in *`foo-wrapper.zig`* and add the `pub` keyword.

---

*foo.zig*

```rs
pub fn hello() void {
 std.debug.print("Hello", .{});
}
```

*foo-wrapper.zig*

```rs
const foo = @import("foo.zig");
pub const hello = foo.hello;
// or do
pub usingnamespace @import("foo.zig");

pub fn helloWorld() void {
 hello();
 std.debug.print(" World", .{});
}
```

*main.zig*

```rs
const foo_wrapper = @import("foo-wrapper.zig");

pub fn main() void {
  foo_wrapper.helloWorld();
  foo_wrapper.hello();
}
```

Comment: `pub const hello = foo.hello;` did it! Thank you!